# Is there a Visual Studio Code Extension command to check an editor group's length?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a Visual Studio Code Extension and I am looking to check the length (amount) of editors in X group.

Thank you

Comment: each group has only 1 editor

Answer (score 0):

```
vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.tabs.length
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?